# Pause embedded youtube on parent modal close javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, hide, bootstrap-modal, pause

So I have a bunch of modals (like 30) each containing some text and an embedded youtube video, I want to pause or refresh the video(so as to put it back to the beginning before the play button was pressed) whenever its parent modal is closed (either by pressing the close button or clicking out of the modal). I would also prefer to do this to all the modals and videos through the same script rather than having a script for each individual one. I know very very little javascript though, does anyone know it this is possible and if so I would love it if you'd help me out a little :)

This is an example of the modal

```
<div aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" class="modal fade news6" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove closer" data-dismiss="modal"></span>
                <div class="col-md-8 vid">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fcZMO1mjArs?color=white&&rel=0&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1>Iraq Update<br><small>- 2003</small></h1>
                <p>Edited for SBS world news evening bulletin</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class news6 on the parent modal is the unique identifier and the other modals have similar names (news3,news4,etc...)

Once again I really appreciate any help with these things :)

Comment: I'm not sure you have control over the video itself, but you could remove and re-add the `iframe`.